# Missing right parenthesis problem in oracle select query

Tags: oracle

I have the below simple select query in oracle.

```
SELECT
    HN.HAND_PERSON_NOTIFICATIONS_GUID,      
    HN.NOTIFICATION_TEXT,
    HN.NOTIFICATION_TYPE,
    HN.NOTIFICATION_DATE,    
    TO_CHAR(HN.CREATE_DATE,'dd-MM-yyyy') AS CREATE_DATE,
    TO_CHAR(HN.CHANGE_DATE,'dd-MM-yyyy') AS CHANGE_DATE,
    TO_CHAR(HN.REG_DATE,'dd-MM-yyyy') AS REG_DATE,
    LU.INIT AS INIT,
    IX.PNR AS CPR,
    IX.NAVN AS FULLNAME
FROM HAND_PERSON_NOTIFICATIONS HN, LM_USER LU, HAND_PERSON_INFO HI, INDIVID_X IX
WHERE HN.HAND_PERSON_INFO_GUID = HI.HAND_PERSON_INFO_GUID
AND HN.REG_USER_GUID = LU.LM_USER_GUID
AND HI.CPR = IX.PNR  
AND HI.HAND_PERSON_INFO_GUID = 'd274579c-3132-485e-a3ea-d5b540c19faf' 
AND HN.NOTIFICATION_TYPE = 'fsfsfs' 
AND TO_DATE(HN.NOTIFICATION_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') BETWEEN TO_DATE('21-07-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('21-07-2022, 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
ORDER BY HN.CREATE_DATE DESC
```

But when I run the query I get the below error:

> ORA-00907: manglende højre parentes
> 00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
> *Cause:
> *Action: Error at Line: 18 Column: 119

**Please be informed that the column type of HN.NOTIFICATION_DATE is Date**.
Can anyone let me know where the problem is?

Comment: You are missing a closing apostrophe: `TO_DATE('21-07-2022, 'DD-MM-YYYY')` should be `TO_DATE('21-07-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY')`

Comment: Never use to_date function on a date column, it is already a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the right parenthesis on `AND TO_DATE('21-07-2022 ,, 'DD-MM-YYYY')`

Try the following query:

```
SELECT
    HN.HAND_PERSON_NOTIFICATIONS_GUID,      
    HN.NOTIFICATION_TEXT,
    HN.NOTIFICATION_TYPE,
    HN.NOTIFICATION_DATE,    
    TO_CHAR(HN.CREATE_DATE,'dd-MM-yyyy') AS CREATE_DATE,
    TO_CHAR(HN.CHANGE_DATE,'dd-MM-yyyy') AS CHANGE_DATE,
    TO_CHAR(HN.REG_DATE,'dd-MM-yyyy') AS REG_DATE,
    LU.INIT AS INIT,
    IX.PNR AS CPR,
    IX.NAVN AS FULLNAME
FROM HAND_PERSON_NOTIFICATIONS HN, LM_USER LU, HAND_PERSON_INFO HI, INDIVID_X IX
WHERE HN.HAND_PERSON_INFO_GUID = HI.HAND_PERSON_INFO_GUID
AND HN.REG_USER_GUID = LU.LM_USER_GUID
AND HI.CPR = IX.PNR  
AND HI.HAND_PERSON_INFO_GUID = 'd274579c-3132-485e-a3ea-d5b540c19faf' 
AND HN.NOTIFICATION_TYPE = 'fsfsfs' 
AND TO_DATE(HN.NOTIFICATION_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') BETWEEN TO_DATE('21-07-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('21-07-2022', 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
ORDER BY HN.CREATE_DATE DESC
```